# How does filter method work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime, reactive-cocoa

```
-(instancetype)filter:(BOOL (^)(id value))block {
NSCParameterAssert(block != nil);

Class class = self.class;

return [[self flattenMap:^ id (id value) {
    if (block(value)) {
        return [class return:value];
    } else {
        return class.empty;
    }
}] setNameWithFormat:@"[%@] -filter:", self.name];
```

}

This is the implementation of filter of ReactiveCocoa.I don't know what this code means.Also I can't get any reference to the second return method.

```
 return [class return:value];
```

Also, what does this instancetype mean? Suppose the value is a string and I check whether its length is greater than 2. What will be returned by using filter method?

Comment: `instancetype` means that if you call this on an `RACSignal`, you'll get an `RACSignal` back, and if you call it on an `RACSequence` you'll get an `RACSequence` back, so that you don't have to downcast from `RACStream`. You usually see it on class methods, though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter method invokes the class method of the current class to get a RACStream subclass using that method. Using `return:` will give a signal that sends the value passed and then completes. Using `empty` gives a signal that immediately sends completed without sending a next value, which removes the value filtered value from the stream thanks to `flattenMap:` switching out the signal with the one being created.

Comment: I didn't notice that the return: method was defined before in this class. However, this method  name is also a little confusing.

Comment: It's a very terse description of what the method actually does, which is neat once you get past that initial confusion.